# build-essential tries to install unrelated package nautilus-dropbox

Tags: apt, dpkg

Whenever I try to install them through the Software Center it will remain at 0% for hours. I instead attempted to install the application I needed by compiling it from source. I needed the `build-essential` package and tried to install it with `apt-get`. Now, it tries to install a bunch of dependencies, along with `dropbox-nautilus`, which just hangs at 100% download for hours as well. Here's the full terminal output:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libunistring0:i386 libgomp1:i386 libcroco3:i386 libgettextpo0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 327 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 818 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,169 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libdpkg-perl all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 [181 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main dpkg-dev all 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6 [468 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main build-essential amd64 11.5ubuntu2.1 [5,816 B]
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot amd64 1.18.2-1 [87.2 kB]
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-perl all 1.19.02-2 [50.7 kB]
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl amd64 0.04-2build2 [12.4 kB]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libalgorithm-merge-perl all 0.08-2 [12.7 kB]
Fetched 818 kB in 5s (136 kB/s)                 
Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
(Reading database ... 234719 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (from .../libdpkg-perl_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Unpacking dpkg-dev (from .../dpkg-dev_1.16.1.2ubuntu7.6_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Unpacking build-essential (from .../build-essential_11.5ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (from .../libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.02-2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (from .../libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-2build2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (from .../libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-2_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up gdebi-core (0.8.5build1) ...
Setting up libcairo-perl (1.081-1build2) ...
Setting up libglib-perl (2:1.241-1) ...
Setting up libpango-perl (1.222-1build1) ...
Setting up libgtk2-perl (2:1.223-1build3) ...
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (0.7.1-2) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/

Downloading Dropbox... 100%
```

What is going on here? And how can I fix it? `apt-get` is completely unusable at the moment.

Comment: It's not `build-essential` that brings in `nautilus-dropbox`. It looks you had tried to install it and then cancelled it halfway, forcing `apt` to try and finish the installation each time you install something, until you remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libdpkg-perl
```

There isn't nautilus-dropbox package in the list. Your problem is seen later:

```
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 327 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
```

You have half-installed or unconfigured packages, which I presume is why Software Center also becomes unresponsive.

The only way to resolve all these issues is to complete the configuration of those packages:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Which should complete the installation of nautilus-dropbox and any other package. Then install build-essentials per usual and it should work.

If for some motive you don't want to install one of the packages being configured, ie. nautilus-dropbox, you can remove them outright:

```
sudo dpkg --remove nautilus-dropbox
```

Comment: I've tried that, and the install hangs at 100%.

Comment: @JonathanBoudreau tried what? what hangs?

Comment: When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, the dropbox install runs, and it will stick at 100% for hours. I essentially get the exact same problem.

Comment: @JonathanBoudreau an alternative, if you are not interested in the software, is removing it with `dkpg --remove nautilus-dropbox`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. If you could add this to your answer I'll mark it as the solution.